# how to Push item into array via mongoose?

Tags: node.js, arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking to push this ObjectId from the Notes Schema: `635b70c1121186eefbbc5718`

into the 'notesId' of this other Category Schema:

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId("635b70c0121186eefbbc5714"),
  name: 'frenchLessons',
  creator: new ObjectId("635aa97815faaa052ae9cfce"),
  notesId: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

What I did was that I found the Category which holds both the name of the category in question and the Id of the current signed in user and tried push method but its not working:

```js
.then(() => {
              return Category.find({ name: categoryName, creator: creator });
            })
            .then((category) => {
              category.notesId.push(note._id); //returns TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
              return category.save();
            });
```

`console.log(category)` returns me the correct document

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to push _id directly to the array.

```
  let data=await Category.findOneAndUpdate({ name: categoryName, creator: creator }, {
    $push: { notesId : note._id},
  });
```